# Is it a myth or a fact that mixing cake/muffin batter too finely can lead to a hard finally baked cake/muffin?

Tags: baking, cake, muffins, quickbread

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Over-stirring muffin mixtures](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/1722/over-stirring-muffin-mixtures)

From here: http://culinaryarts.about.com/od/bakingdesserts/r/plainmuffins.htm

> The key to making great muffins is not overmixing the batter. Once the liquid ingredients are added to the dry, mix the batter by hand just until the flour is moistened, for no more than about ten seconds. Too much mixing can cause the muffins to be dry, tough or misshapen.

and

> The batter should be visibly lumpy, and you may see pockets of dry flour. That's OK! It's extremely important not to overmix the batter, or the resulting muffins will be too hard.

**Is there some scientific reasoning behind this claim?**

Comment: I think this is kind of already answered in [Over-stirring muffin mixtures](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/1722) isn't it?

Comment: @Aaronut Right, and thanks. This looks like a duplicate of that question. I couldn't see that one while creating this (in  similar threads). But, fortunately, this one has got better answers. :) I'll flag this and you should merge its beautiful answers in the other thread.

Comment: We rarely delete duplicates, so nobody's losing anything.